# How to change the background of datalist item using VB.NET code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I want to change the color of the background of an item in `datalist` upon some condition while binding the data? How?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `ItemDataBound` event handler to the datalist

ASPX:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
</asp:DataList>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataListItemEventArgs)             
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
         ' check condition and change styles
    End If
End Sub
```